# Add content to PHP WP excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a complete PHP newbie and I need a solutionto get the most out of this stupid problem with a custom Wordpress theme.

I found the part where excerpts to on index page are 'made' and all I need is to add `"..."` to the end of this part.

```
<?php 

echo wpautop(
    $post->post_excerpt 
    ? $post->post_excerpt 
    : athemes_limit_string(strip_tags($post->post_content), 200) 
); 

?>
```

I tried to add them after this line, but they showed up after the break, but I want them inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP you can add anything you want in the HTML by doing it *outside* of PHP, that here is after the ending `?>` marker:

```
[...] ?> ...
```

Compare: http://php.net/language.basic-syntax.phpmode

I'd say that is the most simple and flexible method when you're concerned about themeing. The second suggestion I would give is to add it as a string to the echo, works by using a comma (`,`):

```
echo wpautop( $p ... nt), 200) ), '...';
                                ^^^^^^^
```

Compare: http://php.net/echo , http://php.net/string

The function in Wordpress for this btw is [`the_excerpt()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) and if you modify a theme, you should just hook in that. Looks like the custom theme you've got is doing things out of the lines. The `the_excerpt` function btw. add that on it's own, you don't need to care.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand what I'm doing a little bit more. :)

Comment: Well just digged through the code, most likely one problem you still might run into is that wpautop is doing crap again. I strongly would say not to use wpautop here, there are better plugins like fancy excerpts that are doing "the best" (tm) excerpts :) - http://wordpress.org/plugins/sem-fancy-excerpt/ - those can also be properly configured, e.g. the style of "..." you want to add here.

Comment: I'm pretty satisfied with how it looks now, I just wanted those three dots at the end - http://blog.alpner.com/ ...but I'll sure bookmark that plugin. Tnx again.

Answer (score 1):

There are better ways of doing this, but to answer your question:

```
echo wpautop( $post->post_excerpt ? $post->post_excerpt : athemes_limit_string(strip_tags($post->post_content), 200).'...' );
```

Comment: So, it's not the excerpt that is being printed then. Try adding it here instead: `athemes_limit_string(strip_tags($post->post_content), 200).'...'`.